# In WPF/Prism, what happens with a CompositeCommand when a DelegateCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged is fired?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, delegatecommand

Say that I have a CompositeCommand with a lot of DelegateCommands registered.

If one of the child DelegateCommands fires up RaiseCanExecuteChanged, this will result in firing the event `CompositeCommand.CanExecuteChanged`, raising this same event in the other children, or it will only affect the active DelegateCommand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured this out. By analyzing the internals of Prism, I noticed that the `CompositeCommand` registers itself in its children's `CanExecuteChanged` event. Thus, everytime a registered command raises the `CanExecuteChanged` handler, the composite command does the same in itself and in all of its children.